# When using subclipse over ssh is there a way to not enter my password so much?

Tags: svn, ssh, subclipse

I have set up subclipse and my svn server to run over ssh. Everything is working great, except I have to enter my password five times to do one checkout. Is there a way I can store the password so it re-uses it?

Comment: I don't know if it is even possible to save the password, but have you considered using private key authentication instead?

Comment: Don't know how to set that up with subclipse. I guesss that's kinda what I'm looking for.

Comment: Basically, you need to generate a public/private key pair, register the private part with an SSH authentication agent (e.g. Pageant from the PuTTY family) on your client and set up the the public part as an 'autorized key' with the ssh on the server side. Depending on what kind of access you have to the server, you may need the assistance of your sysamin for the latter part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot "push" credentials into an SSH client.  The right answer is the one that Andreas Baus entered as a comment.  Configure your SSH server/client to use keys for authentication and then your SSH client can just connect by using your key.